# What is the function of syntax "no_option_page " and "PlatfomType" in this manifest.json of an Extension from Webstore

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have tried to modify a chrome extension from Webstore. After downloading the crx file and unzipped it, I have found some strange syntax in the manfest.json

If I trying to install the unpacked extension to Chrome it will raise an error.

Unrecognized manifest key 'no_options_page'.

Unrecognized manifest key 'platformType'.

There is many samples of a manifest file using metadata "option" but could not find "no_option_page". Is it a custom declaration?

```
},
"no_options_page": "options.html",
"platformType": "prod"
```

}

Could not find an explanation anywhere to fix this problem

Comment: Just like the browser says those aren't valid keys. Someone added them by mistake.

Comment: They appear in [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rating-program-extension/imbankdmoclhcdmdejkklikkpaidaeij). At least `platformType`is used in the code to determine whether the extension is in production or testing mode. `no_options_page` is not used as far as I know.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko, Yes, I ask about the extension that you pointed above. I just want to hardcoding my user name and password in the login page. If I modifying installed code from the web store, Chrome will raise an error as corrupted extension.